# Как работает эта функция в пайтон?

Tags: python, массивы, функции, list, рекурсия

```
def quicksort(array):
if len(array) < 2:
    return array
else:
    pivot = array[0]
    less = [i for i in array[1:] if i < pivot]
    greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot]

    return quicksort(less) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)
print(quicksort([3,4,5,2,1]))
```

я так понимаю, что less берёт меньшие числа чем pivot, а greater берёт большие чем pivot, но по какому принципу эти две переменные это делают? Почему в `[i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot]` перед циклом стоит i? И в чём суть условия `if i > pivot]`? После этого условия же ничего не стоит.

Если так важно, то это из книжки "Грокаем алгоритмы", на странице 92, издание 2022 года.

Comment: Самое интересное, что эта функция нерабочая, так что не всем книжкам можно доверять. `print(quicksort([3,2,2,2,1]))`

Comment: @MBo `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. она работает

Comment: @MBo У меня вполне работает

Comment: @TrueTruffle И что она выдаёт для приведенного примера?

Comment: @n1tr0xs Я дал пример ввода, который она не сможет правильно обработать.

Comment: Собственно, достаточно  в одном из условий поставить "или равно"

Comment: В этой функции одна серьёзная ошибка, два косяка по производительности, один косяк по интерфейсу и один оформительский. Ищите другие книги.

Comment: это нормальная книга

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется - `list comprehenshion` (генераторы списков).

Позволяют создавать списки "на лету" по некоторому условию.

Как это работает:

1. Всё записывается в квадратных скобках, по аналогии с тем, как создавать список.
2. Далее указывается тот элемент, который будет помещен в итоговый список (в вашем случае - это элемент `i`)
3. Далее определяется то, откуда этот элемент берется (`i for i in array[1:]`), то есть в новый список будут добавлены все элементы из `array[1:]`, если бы например было написано `i**2 for i in array[1:]`, то добавлялись бы не сами элементы, а их квадраты.
4. И дополнительно можно ещё написать некоторое условие, по которому элементы будут добавляться в новый список, `if i > pivot`

В заключение имеем, что мы получаем новый список из всех элементов `array[1:]`, которые превосходят значение `pivot`.

Это базовая информация про `list comprehenshion`, на данном этапе её должно быть достаточно.

Если хочется узнать подробнее, то всегда есть [официальная документация](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: выберу ваш ответ как принятый! Спасибо

Comment: кстати, вы мне уже два раза помогли)

Comment: @TrueTruffle да, я вас помню) Вы молодец, что читаете умные книги и стараетесь разобраться, при таком подходе вы точно сможете многого добиться)

Comment: Спасибо! Ваши слова мотивируют)

Answer (score 2):

В данном примере используется [`list comrehension`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/) (генератор списка).
Если развернуть его в привычный цикл, то это выглядит так:

```
less = []
for i in array[1:]:
    if i<pivot:
        less.append(i)
```

Соответсвенно:

- `i` в начале генератора - это элемент, из котого собирается список;
- `for i in array[1:]` откуда этот элемент берется;
- `if i<pivot` - фильтрация элементов.

Comment: спасибо! теперь я понял

Answer (score 1):

```
[i for i in array[1:] if i < pivot]
```

— Это не совсем цикл, это list comprehension. Специальное выражение, свойственное python, для удобной сокращённой записи циклов.

Означает: сделать новый список, где будет каждый **i** из всех **i**, находящихся в array[:1], но только если **i** меньше pivot.

Вместо i можно использовать здесь любое понятное вам имя.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: спасибо! теперь я понял